# After inserting into database the value is not read in the first time

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf, inner-join

I'm creating a CRUD application using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, I was doing it with only one table and It was ok, after added a new table and take data with INNER JOIN, then problem happen.

After insert a new field, it's saved right in DB, but when I select it in the application **don't** brings the description of join in the first time.

The worst thing is that is only occurs in the first time, if I load the page again the description is loaded correctly.

I've already changed FetchType of `@OneToOne` annotation from `LAZY` to `EAGER`, tried with `@ManyToOne` too.

I've already changed `insertable = true, updatable = true` of `@JoinColumn` annotation;

Both tries didn't worked.

Livro.java:

```
@Entity
public class Livros {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idLivro;
    private String titulo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_categoria", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
```

Categoria.java:

```
@Entity
public class Categoria {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idCategoria;
    private String descricaoCategoria;
```

consultar.html:

```
            <tr th:each="livro : ${listaLivros}" >
                <td th:text="${livro.titulo}">Título do livro</td>
                <td th:text="${livro.categoria.idCategoria}">ID da Categoria do livro</td>
                <td th:text="${livro.categoria.descricaoCategoria}">Categoria do livro</td>
```

MainController.java:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listaLivros", livroRepository.findAll());
    return "index";
}
```

After insert statement, I'm loading the table:

```
@PostMapping("/incluir")
public String postIncluir(Model model, @ModelAttribute Livros livro) {
    livroRepository.save(livro);
    return index(model);
}
```

[Debug inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xdHh.png)

In MysqlWorkbench is recorded okay:
[MysqlWorkbench inner join query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIRk2.png)

In the page don't load the field, as could be seen in the inspect:
[First load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZvCU.png)

If i load the page again, the field is loaded correctly:
[Second load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmqOV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
@PostMapping("/incluir")
public String postIncluir(Model model, @ModelAttribute Livros livro) {
    livroRepository.saveAndFlush(livro); //THIS LINE CHANGE
    return index(model);
}
```

-Another workaround is redirecting to the list after calling the save method. This would surely call the findall method that would bring all the updated data.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I changed as you said (needed to change LivroRepository to extends JpaRepository (was CrudRepository)) but it didn't worked, I used a workarround way to fix the problem, I created a View, but by this way need to create a few classes... There's a way to "flush" before findAll()?

Comment: After save i'm calling index, that's where findAll is called. It brings the id, but not the description